# Корректное отображение приложения на планшетах и смартфонах Android

Tags: android-sdk, android

Приложение должно корректно отображаться на всех Android смартфонах и планшетах. Не могу понять, как мне указать размеры элементов отдельно для телефонов различных плотностей, и отдельно для различных планшетов? То есть с какими названиями должны быть папки value?

Comment: Данное руководство содержит всю необходимую информацию http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один момент: плотность экрана не зависит от того планшет это или телефон. Другими словами может быть и телефон и планшет с мелкими пикселями, средними или крупными.
Для этих целей предусмотрены каталоги:

```
drawable
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-xxxhdpi
drawable-nodpi
```

В каталог `drawable` обычно ложат ресурсы которые не зависят от density, т.е. XML-ки.

В каталог `drawable-nodpi` обычно ложат ресурсы которые не будут автоматически скалиться андроидом.

Если нужна отдельная компоновка для телефонов и планшетов, учитывая ориентацию + обычно у телефонов только портрет ориентация, а у планшетов и портрет и ландскейп(чтобы достичь этого используется [этот метод](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14793611/1159507)):

```
layout
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw600dp-land
```

Таким образом каталог `layout` будет использоваться для телефонов, `layout-sw600dp` для планшетов шириной свыше 600dp, т.е. по факту 6" и 10", `layout-sw600dp-land` также для планшетов но в  landscape orientation.

Если необходимо задать более детальные размеры элементов и отступов это обычно выносят в `dimens.xml`, в values:

```
values
values-sw360dp
values-sw600dp
values-sw720dp
[values-sw600dp-land] - опционально
[values-sw720dp-land] - опционально
```

Где `values` - для небольших телефонов и значений по умолчанию (порядка `sw320dp`), `sw360dp` - для больших телефонов (фаблетов) типа Samsung Galaxy Note, `sw600dp` - для 7", `sw720dp` - для 10"

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А если я хочу отдельно указать размеры для телефонов различных разрешений и отдельно планшетов?

Comment: @iamtihonov размеры чего?

Comment: @ander допустим отступов различных view

Comment: @iamtihonov в dimens их повыносить, в ответе это указанно

Comment: @ander Спасибо ещё раз, до меня дошло! Сразу не понял)